# Eclipse cannot find imports : com.oreilly.servlet.* , org.apache.commons.io.*

Tags: java, eclipse

```
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=euc-kr"%>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" %>
<%@page import="com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.DefaultFileRenamePolicy"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.io.*"%>
<%
String saveFolder = "C:/Jsp/myapp/WebContent/ch12/filestorage";
String encType = "euc-kr";
int maxSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
try {
    MultipartRequest multi = null;
    multi = new MultipartRequest(request, saveFolder, maxSize,
            encType, new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
    Enumeration params = multi.getParameterNames();

    while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) params.nextElement();
        String value = multi.getParameter(name);
        out.println(name + " = " + value + "<br/>");
    }

    Enumeration files = multi.getFileNames();
    while (files.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) files.nextElement();
        String filename = multi.getFilesystemName(name);
        String original = multi.getOriginalFileName(name);
        String type = multi.getContentType(name);
        File f = multi.getFile(name);
        out.println("파라미터 이름 : " + name + "<br/>");
        out.println("실제 파일 이름 : " + original + "<br/>");
        out.println("저장된 파일 이름 : " + filename + "<br/>");
        out.println("파일 타입 : " + type + "<br/>");
        if (f != null) {
            out.println("크기 : " + f.length()+"바이트");
            out.println("<br/>");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println(ioe);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
%>
```

this is an example code. the problem is very simple.
eclipse simply cannot find imports even if the external libraries are stored in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.

I tried reinstallation, searching on the internet and etc for hours
but I still cannot find any solutions for this.
I triple,quadra checked import directive. I cannot see any spelling problem

why does this happen to my eclipse?(I am using eclipse oxygen)

Comment: If you decide against using dependency mangement like maven (which might be okay for a learning project) you have to make sure that the libs are part of the projects build path. You can do that by right-clicking on the projects root -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

Comment: Which external libraries?

Comment: I intend to use commons-io-2.6-src.jar, cos-26Dec2008.jar and commons-fileupload-1.3.jar I am already using mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar in my project but only mysql connector is correctly detected and functioning

Comment: and I already tried build path solution, it does not make any difference

Answer (score -1):

Download `cos.jar` from: https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/cos

- Right click build path
- configure build path,
- add `cos.jar` to add external jar

Comment: I would view downloading from a site like jar-download.com as highly dangerous.  Use maven-central or perhaps the original github repo.